# Optimizer for an RNN using pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

[The pytorch RNN tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_classification_tutorial.html) uses

```
for p in net.parameters():
    p.data.add_(p.grad.data, alpha = -learning_rate)
```

as optimizer. Does anyone know the difference between doing that or doing the classical `optimizer.step()`, once an optimizer has been defined explicitly? Is there some special consideration one has to take into when training RNNs in regards to the optimizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the example uses a simple gradient descent algorithm to update:

[image: p_{t+1}=p_t-\alpha \mathrm{grad}_pJ_t]
where J is cost.

If the optimizer your using is a simple gradient descent tool, then there is no difference between using `optimizer.step()` and the code in the example.

I know that's not a super exciting answer to your question, because it depends on how the `step()` function is written. Check out [this page](http://mcneela.github.io/machine_learning/2019/09/03/Writing-Your-Own-Optimizers-In-Pytorch.html) to learn about `step()` and [this page](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html) to learn more about `torch.optim`.